# battery consumption of an application on blackberry

Tags: mobile, blackberry, gprs

Is there any App/ Method / Process that i can use to get the battery consumption of a single app in blackberry? I am using 9300. My application uses GPRS and sends data over internet.

Till now i have been using a thread which tells me the difference between battery levels after an hour of a phone using my app and a phone not using my app.

Please suggest a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately BlackBery is not really open, clear and documented platform.

The best numbers that I got from conference in Amsterdam [Info](https://plus.google.com/photos/102191796240841888189/albums/5822997679587023729)

Comment: My pleasure. I've asked why these numbers aren't public. No response

Comment: I used your information to show some approximate but useful analysis. thanks. Any ideas on how does BB measure in comparision with Iphone and other mobile platforms in this regard (in use of GPS and Networking)?

Comment: @shashankkb I don't think you can compare between platforms. There are so many different Android devices and BlackBerry models that comparing is difficult even between devices of the same platform. there are [some rangkings in the net](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=mobile+phone+battery+life+comparison&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t) but most of them only cover talk time.

Comment: @MisterSmith : Thanks. I am considering moving from blackberry to android. The customers complain that the battery backup is very poor...

Comment: @shashankkb There are so many reasons to abandon BB Java development, but IMHO the battery is not very different from what a mid-range android offers. The way your software is designed plays a major role. For instance, a service registering a GPS listener with a relatively small period and making a few network connections can drain a battery pretty fast.

Comment: @shashankkb Another good example: Most laptops I've worked with cannot stand 1h of playing flash videos over Wi-Fi (And I complain a lot about this). On the other hand, Li-Ion technology sucks.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reliable way to tell how much battery your app has used. As you are already doing, you can retrieve the levels before and after calling `DeviceInfo.getBatteryLevel`, but the measured difference includes the battery used by other apps too.

Comment: Yes, but i don't find that reliable.. though it will be approx... my app uses GPS and networking.. two biggest consumers of battery.. I was hoping to pinpoint it even more...

Comment: Thats good useful information that i can use to home in on my app even further. Thanks